Laravel Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `distrisalsas`.`product_details` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is inc
i have a problem, i am trying to create my tables in mySql: products, brands, references and product details using migrations in laravel 11, but when i run the php artisan migrate command i get these errors:
    2024_05_16_010921_create_product_details_table  45.49ms FAIL

    Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

    SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `distrisalsas`.`product_details` 
    (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Connection: mysql, SQL: 
    alter table `product_details` add constraint `product_details_product_id_foreign` foreign 
    key (`product_id`) references `products` (`id`) on delete set null on update cascade)      

    at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:813
    809▕                     $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    810▕                 );
    811▕             }
    812▕
    ➜ 813▕             throw new QueryException(     
    814▕                 $this->getName(), $query, 
    $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    815▕             );
    816▕         }
    817▕     }

    1   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:571
    PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 
   `distrisalsas`.`product_details` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly 
    formed")")

   2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:571
   PDOStatement::execute()

this is my code:
return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('product');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
};

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('brands', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('brand');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('brands');
    }
};

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('references', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('reference');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('references');
    }
};

y
return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('product_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();            
            $table->foreignId('product_id')
            ->constrained()
            ->cascadeOnUpdate()
            ->nullOnDelete();
            $table->foreignId('brand_id')
            ->nullable()
            ->constrained()
            ->cascadeOnUpdate()
                ->nullOnDelete();
            $table->foreignId('reference_id')
                ->nullable()
                ->constrained()
                ->cascadeOnUpdate()
                ->nullOnDelete();       
            $table->decimal('price')
                ->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            });
    }


    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('product_details');
    }
};


I have already checked the tables of brands, products, references in my database and the ids are BIGINT(20) with attribute UNSIGNED
I appreciate any help

You forgot to add ->nullable() after $table->foreignId('product_id')
Here's the correct code for product_details table:
return new class extends Migration {
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 */
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('product_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('product_id')
            ->nullable()
            ->constrained()
            ->cascadeOnUpdate()
            ->nullOnDelete();
        $table->foreignId('brand_id')
            ->nullable()
            ->constrained()
            ->cascadeOnUpdate()
            ->nullOnDelete();
        $table->foreignId('reference_id')
            ->nullable()
            ->constrained()
            ->cascadeOnUpdate()
            ->nullOnDelete();
        $table->decimal('price')
            ->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 */
public function down(): void
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('product_details');
}

};
